# Change path of custom logs in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple web service which need to log every request being done on it.
For this I use the CakePHP custom log engine:

```
$this->log('Log of the request.', 'myLog');
```

This log file is located in `app/tmp/logs/myLog.log`

The problem is: I need to display the log on my website. Is there a way to change the location of custom logs in CakePHP ?

I read on the documentation that I can use:

```
CakeLog::config('custom_directory', array(
  'engine' => 'FileLog',
  'path' => 'webroot/my-logs/'
));
```

But I only want my logs to be saved in this custom directory, not every log.

Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply, after recording the log entry, copy the file to the destination that you want.

i.e:

```
$this->log('Log of the request.', 'myLog');
// copy file code here
```

Checkout [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) documentation

**Notice that**, it's better and easier to use the absolute system path for both source and destination.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using copy because of the need of absolute path but I think this will be my best option. Thanks!

Comment: The absolute path is not problem at all, there is `CakePHP` constant that offers it to the base path. I think it is `ROOT` you could find its definition in `webroot/index.php`

Comment: Indeed. I am going to use that. Too bad there is no built-in function to redirect log files.

Comment: We can see it that way haha

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you can do to a single log file, but it occurs to me perhaps make a symbolic link from the log to the webroot.

```
ln -s /var/www/app/tmp/logs/myLog.log /var/www/app/webroot/my-logs/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is a good idea but the problem is I have a new log file on each request..